# Magento 1.9 Get a custom field from order table programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-field

In my Magento 1.9, I have an extension fooman surcharge installed. and the extension added some extra fields into **sales_flat_order**

How can I programmatically retrieve the data from these fields?

for example in the screenshot, I want to get the data from the field `fooman_surcharge_amount`.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get values from order object as follows.

```
$surchargeAmount = $order->getData('fooman_surcharge_amount');
```

Where `$order` is previously loaded order object.

Comment: Thanks Kishan for answering: $order->getFoomanSurchargeAmount() would work too.

Comment: @KristofatFooman Thanks for the comment, I can not find where is this getFoomanSurchargeAmount() function defined in your extension. How does it work for the getFoomanSurchargeAmount()?

Comment: @xxx that is the standard magic getter from Magento. Essentially when you write $order->getFoomanSurchargeAmount()  it translates this into $order->getData('fooman_surcharge_amount')

Answer (score 2):

You can load order by **entity id**

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999); //use an entity id here
```

Or by **increment_id**

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('10000001'); //use a real increment order id here
```

you can see all field value of order by

```
print_r($order->getData());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this array and dump it via:

```
print_r($order->getData());
// or
var_dump($order->getData());
```

You will get an output like this with print_r():

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 2
    [state] => new
    [status] => pending
// ...
```